# OpenLayers - pop up not working

Tags: openlayers, popup

I'm using this code which I got from U-PENN geog 585:

https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog585/node/718

```
                  var response = JSON.parse(event.text);
                  if(response.features.length !== 0){
                    var returnedFeature = response.features[0];
                    // Configure the popup
                    map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                      "marketInfo",
                      map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                      null,
                      "<b>" + returnedFeature.properties.NAME + "</b><br />" + returnedFeature.properties.ADDRESS,
                      null,
                      true
                    ));
```

I have the webmap up and all of the layers and basemap are rendering ok but when I click on a feature the cursor just spins and spins with no end. I can still navigate on the map and pan around, zoom in and out, but as soon as I stop navigating the spinning cursor resumes and a pop up never generates. I'm a complete nube to web mapping. Tried looking at a few other posts with pop up issues but couldn't see the same cause.

Comment: Does the WMSGetFeatureInfo work and receiving data? Hint: perform a manual getFeatureInfo request or check your Browsers Developer Tools Network tab and check the activity after clicking a feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tiles making the baselayer were stored in a file folder in my docs. It was able to render but nothing would come back because of a mismatch from what was on local host and the location of the tiles. I put the files into the same folder as the webroot for local host (C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.10.3\webapps\site_folder\tiles) and it worked like a charm.